# libcloud and GCP. How to autheticate using service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api-python-client, libcloud

I am trying to use Apache libcloud to access GCP and hopefully be able to launch compute instances. So, following the documentation, I have created a service account on GCP associated with my email and given it the owner access for the moment. After that, I am using libcloud as follows:

```
from libcloud.compute.types import Provider
from libcloud.compute.providers import get_driver
ComputeEngine = get_driver(Provider.GCE)

driver = ComputeEngine('luca@googlemail.com', 'gcp-key.json', project='first-gcp')
```

This actually displays a URL and asks me to enter a code from it. When I click on the URL, I get the error message:

```
The OAuth client was not found.
```

This was not the workflow I was envisioning. I thought providing the secret key would just let me in and I would be able to then use methods for launching instances etc. So, I am not sure if I am doing the right thing by using a service account on GCP for this.

So, I get the following asking for a code:

So I get this:

```
Please Go to the following URL and sign in:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcompute+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdevstorage.full_control+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fndev.clouddns.readwrite&state=Libcloud+Request
Enter Code:
```

How should I approach this? We will be a few remote people working on this eventually so ideally each person will have their own key to use and this should happen in a bit autonomous way in the sense if codes do not need to be entered manually, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Console (https://cloud.google.com/console), select your project. When your project is open, select "APIs & auth" and then "Credentials" as shown below:

In Development: Preferably make one for each, could use one for all for testing purposes.

In production: For each user to use this service, create a service account.

When you download the service account, you should have it as a `.pem` or `.json` file. Use the email address from the service account (if you open the json/pem you shd be able to see the email) and give it the correct values region/project/email and path to the pem file.

The code you're using is correct, avoid using the name "ComputeEngine" since it may be a keyword (even though it probably isn't, best practice)

```
from libcloud.compute.types import Provider
from libcloud.compute.providers import get_driver
Driver = get_driver(Provider.GCE)
gce = Driver('your_service_account_email', 'path_to_pem_file',
             datacenter='us-central1-a',
             project='your_project_id')
```

Have a look [here](https://libcloud.apache.org/blog/2014/02/18/libcloud-0-14-and-google-cloud-platform.html) If you're confused on any steps. But this should def work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, it seems I am going through the service account route but I am not sure how to get this code that it asks for. Somehow my google console looks a bit different from the one linked by libcloud docs.

Comment: In the top left corner click the three bars, then click "API and Services" and then click "Credentials" and get your service account from here.

Comment: yes, I have that and the credentials and the JSON key files are all set. I am more confused about the code tat is being asked when I try and login? Do I need to do this everytime I try and connect? is there a way to bypass it and just use the PEM file for login?

Comment: So with supplying the pem files, you need to provide some additional information like your project, email the pem is registered to, region you want to connect to. This information is as important as your pem file. You could create a wrapper over this if you just want to use your pem file. 
Keep everything hardcoded, get email from pem file, use only pem file.

Comment: Yup, that was i. I could not use the default email that I had the account with, I needed the generated email in the JSON file. Thanks! I still have other issues but that is probably also more with the enabling some settings.

Comment: Alright. If you post another question, leave the link here and I can try helping you however I can! :)